# C++ template type and variadic data of that type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a compile time matrix as template parameter

```
template<typename TROW, TROW... TMATRIX>
struct  CTestMatrix
{
    constexpr std::tuple<TROW...> GetData() { return TMATRIX; }
};
```

```
int main()
{

    CTestMatrix<decltype(std::make_tuple('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')),
        std::make_tuple('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
        std::make_tuple('F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'),
        std::make_tuple('K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'),
    > cTestMatrix{};
return 0;
}
```

I get this error..

> error C2993: 'std::tuple<char,char,char,char,char>': is not a valid type for non-type template parameter 'TMATRIX'
> MSVC\14.34.31933\include\tuple(232,40): message : 'tuple<char,char,char,char>' is not a
>
> error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'CTestMatrix'
>
> error C2783: 'CTestMatrix<TROW,TMATRIX...> CTestMatrix(void)': could not deduce template >

> message : see declaration of 'CTestMatrix'
>
> error C2780: 'CTestMatrix<TROW,TMATRIX...> CTestMatrix(CTestMatrix<TROW,TMATRIX...>)': > >

> message : see declaration of 'CTestMatrix'public base class

> expects 1 arguments - 0 providedargument for 'TROW'

Comment: As the error says your `std::tuple` cannot be used as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: @wohlstad Why not ?

Comment: Not any type can be used for a NTTP. You can see the requirements [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). To be honest I didn't analyze all the requirements, but I reckon `std::tuple` does not satisfy them.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you cannot use a tuple as a template parameter. Also, you cannot return packs as tuple, those are different things.

The correct code would be this:

```
CTestMatrix<char,
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
> cTestMatrix{};
```

And the class:

```
template<typename TROW, TROW... TMATRIX>
struct  CTestMatrix
{
    constexpr std::array<TROW, sizeof...(TMATRIX)> GetData() { return {TMATRIX...}; }
};
```

As you can notice, a pack cannot be used as is. You have to expand it to be valid code. `sizeof...` is one type of pack expansion that yields the size of the pack. `<pack>...` will expand each element one after the other, comma separated. Fold expression also is a form of expansion.

By itself, packs are not an entity you can use and manipulate in code except by expanding it.

---

If you want to send one non type template parameter that contains all values, you can in C++20:

```
template<std::array data>
struct CTestMatrix
{
    constexpr decltype(data) GetData() { return data; }
};
```

And use it as such:

```
CTestMatrix<{
    std::array{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'},
    std::array{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'},
    std::array{'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'},
    std::array{'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'},
}> cTestMatrix{};
```

Comment: `array<array<..>, ..>` seems more appropriate for **matrix**. (or dimension parameter with flat array).

Comment: @Jarod42 of course. I didn't notice OP's code had nested tuple